# Stackify not using proxy in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, http-proxy, stackify

In a ASP.Net Core website I am using *NLog* with a *StackifyTarget* to log to *Stackify Retrace*. Our code is running behind a corporate HTTP proxy.

I have some custom code that returns a WebProxy.
The WebProxy is then set on `StackifyLib.Utils.HttpClient.CustomWebProxy`, in the *Configure* method of the *StartUp.cs*.

When a log is written, it is written successfully to file, but not to the StackifyTarget.

When I investigate the network traffic using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I can see that there are *407/Proxy AuthenticationRequired* errors for outbound traffic to the Stackify servers.

Using the same StackifyTarget in a WinForms application, .Net Framework 4.7.2, it just works fine:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

When I set a breakpoint on the *Log.Info*, I can see that the proxy information is still set on the *StackifyLib*.
How can have StackifyLib work correctly with the proxy, in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Think you have to contact `support@stackify.com` and have them fix the existing issue: https://github.com/stackify/stackify-api-dotnet/issues/81 by using HttpClientHandler as recommended by Microsoft: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28780#issuecomment-378322214

Comment: The custom code that assigns proxy to `CustomWebProxy` could also try and assign this first `System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;` (As the very first thing in the application, before Stackify-HttpClient is created).

Comment: @RolfKristensen: it worked! It seems that when the proxy is set after StackifyLib is initialized, it isn't picking up the settings anymore. If you add it as an answer, I'll vote for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom code that assigns proxy to CustomWebProxy could also try and assign this first:

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;
```

As the very first thing in the application, before Stackify-HttpClient is created.

Answer (score 0):

Stackify has 2 docs that may help with this:
https://docs.stackify.com/docs/troubleshoot-errors-and-logs-net-configurations
https://docs.stackify.com/docs/http-proxies-configure

If either of these do not work you can submit a ticket to them to support@stackify.com